# LDA Topic Modeling Producing Identical/Empty Topics

Tags: python, text-mining, gensim, lda

I am topic modeling on two large text documents (around 500-750 KB) and am asking for ten topics. I keep getting a repeat of two topics. Could this be an issue of the small number of documents? Or should I change the alpha/beta parameters?

Here is the code for the model part:

```
`lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=10, 
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=2,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha='auto',
                                           per_word_topics=True)`
```

Here are the topics:

```
[(0,
  '0.005*"city" + 0.004*"police" + 0.003*"people" + 0.003*"thank" + '
  '0.003*"know" + 0.003*"want" + 0.002*"go" + 0.002*"say" + 0.002*"time" + '
  '0.002*"cop"'),
 (1,
  '0.001*"people" + 0.001*"cop" + 0.001*"city" + 0.001*"want" + 0.001*"go" + '
  '0.001*"police" + 0.001*"thank" + 0.001*"time" + 0.001*"know" + 0.001*"say"'),
 (2,
  '0.001*"people" + 0.001*"police" + 0.001*"city" + 0.001*"thank" + '
  '0.001*"want" + 0.001*"cop" + 0.001*"go" + 0.001*"know" + 0.001*"say" + '
  '0.001*"make"'),
 (3,
  '0.002*"city" + 0.002*"people" + 0.001*"know" + 0.001*"want" + '
  '0.001*"police" + 0.001*"go" + 0.001*"say" + 0.001*"vote" + 0.001*"time" + '
  '0.001*"cop"'),
 (4,
  '0.001*"city" + 0.001*"police" + 0.001*"cop" + 0.001*"people" + 0.001*"go" + '
  '0.001*"thank" + 0.001*"want" + 0.001*"vote" + 0.001*"make" + 0.001*"time"'),
 (5,
  '0.020*"city" + 0.014*"people" + 0.013*"police" + 0.011*"cop" + 0.010*"go" + '
  '0.010*"thank" + 0.009*"want" + 0.009*"know" + 0.008*"say" + 0.006*"time"'),
 (6,
  '0.001*"city" + 0.001*"go" + 0.001*"know" + 0.001*"people" + 0.001*"police" '
  '+ 0.001*"cop" + 0.001*"want" + 0.001*"vote" + 0.000*"say" + 0.000*"time"'),
 (7,
  '0.002*"city" + 0.001*"people" + 0.001*"police" + 0.001*"thank" + 0.001*"go" '
  '+ 0.001*"want" + 0.001*"know" + 0.001*"cop" + 0.001*"vote" + 0.001*"say"'),
 (8,
  '0.003*"city" + 0.003*"people" + 0.003*"police" + 0.002*"thank" + 0.002*"go" '
  '+ 0.002*"know" + 0.002*"vote" + 0.002*"want" + 0.002*"say" + 0.002*"time"'),
 (9,
  '0.017*"people" + 0.014*"city" + 0.012*"police" + 0.010*"go" + 0.010*"thank" '
  '+ 0.010*"want" + 0.009*"know" + 0.009*"say" + 0.009*"vote" + 0.008*"time"')]
```

The visualization:

```
`# Visualize the topics
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)
vis
`
```

[see picture of visualization here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TK8x.png)

I have tried changing the parameters some, but haven't seen results. It's hard to find what the normal range for alpha and beta parameters are.

Comment: I don't see an attached pic - maybe forgot to include? (You can edit your Q to add.) I do see just 3 repeated lines of pyLDAvis code - is that really all the code? Your quoted output showing 10 topics implies the LDA step did create the requested number of topics, so maybe the issue showing you only 2 is a visualization code/defaults issue.

Comment: That said, modeling just 2 docs as mixes of 10 distinct topics might give sensible topics, as you've really only got data giving a single "doc A versus doc B" dimension-of-contrast - & extracting 10 dimensions-of-distinction from just a one A-vs-B is tough. So, in addition to any other param tweaks, try to provide a set of docs far more numerous than your target number of topics. (It may be sufficient to just break your 2 docs into sections, as logically as practical: chapters or sections or if needed even paragraphs or arbitrary ranges. That *may* improve the meaningfulness of found topics.)

Comment: re @gojomo sorry about that, i fixed the missing picture and the repeated code. Your second comment is super helpful context for a topic modeling-newbie. I didn't realize it would be comparing docs like that. I guess I'm surprised that it only seems to give one topic per document though? Also, I've been trying out various methods of dividing the docs into smaller docs, but nothing has worked. if you have any suggestions on how to do that without having to do it manually that would be super helpful.

Comment: From your image, it seems it's plotting all 10 topics - but maybe only 1 & 2 have a nitceable diameter. I think that's consistent with the idea the main problem is the tiny number of documents. LDA works on a "bag of words" representation, just overall word frequencies, no sectioning/ordering. So (eg) your ~750KB doc (maybe 125k words, a book?) can only be contrasted, topic-wise with one other ~500KB doc. How would it detect any more than 2 broad topics, from that little comparative contrast? (The words are opaque tokens to the algorithm, with meaning only via co-occurring frequencies.)

Comment: The docs probably have some sensible detectable break points, like chapter headings, which even in very-plain text may be evident from things like extra newlines around an otherwise underpunctuated (no trailing period) short phrase. Or, if they don't maybe you can go back to the source & ensure such hints are retained, at least long enough to break them up. But even if you an't do that, just picking an arbitrary N words, and breaking the docs every N words, might work fine. (Personally, if I wanted 10 topics I'd want at least 10^2 contrasting docs, if not far more.) Try it & see if it works!

Comment: I've broken up my documents into 60 20 kb sized chunks and can now get max 5 different topics. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you "max 5 different topics"? Does that mean, on some (rigorous or eyeball-adhoc) eval, the results seem good when you specify 5 topics, but then no-good when you specify 6? Given that changing 2 docs to 60 helped, you could chunk them further. You could also try tweaking other LDA parameters. (If you have an automated score for how well the topics meet some downstream need, it becomes easy to 'grid-search' many different possible model parameter values, across some ranges of plausible values, to find the best combo. )

Comment: After about 5 topics, topics are repeated exactly

Comment: Odd but perhaps a bug in prep, or deficiency/peculiarity of your data. Is your data natural-language with its characteristic large-vocabularies & zipfian word-frequencies? How many unique words? (That your Q's shown topics *all* show only the same 10 words is weird, suggestive of a very-atypical corpus or very-buggy corpus-prep.)

Comment: As I'm playing with it, I'm finding it seems very dependent on the update_every parameter. With smaller update_every numbers, which are still bigger than chunksize, I can get closer to 10 distinct topics. Why would this be? I'm not sure how many unique words, but there's a lot.

Comment: You can get the number of words by checking `len(dictionary)` of the `dictionary` that you used to create your bag-of-words `corpus`.